# Rails 4: sort collection by array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a method that sorts a collection by an array of `ids` like so:

```
def selected_components
  ids = @document.publications.rank(:position).map(&:component_id)
  Component.find(ids).sort_by { |c| ids.index(c.id) }
end
```

This works fine, but I want to sort the result by the order of `ids` as efficiently as possible. Apparently my method is not the most efficient, although I'm not 100% why that is.

Why isn't this so efficient? Any advice? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure: if you search for efficiently, you must let the db do the work.

First, eager load publications with its components:

```
@document = Document.includes(publications: :component).find_by(...)
```

Then rank and map the components:

```
def selected_components
  @document.publications.rank(:position).map(&:component)
end
```

Now, selected_components don't need to do db access. Also, you don't need to sort data two times, only one (in rank).

**Edited**: Eager load, its recomended as a best practice to fix the n + 1 issue [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).